# ImportError "cannot import name 'cross_validate'"

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn

I am using Python 3, and tried to import Cross_validate. However there's always this error showing the importaiton is not successful. 
I am using sklearn 0.18

`from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate`

and got this error

`ImportError "cannot import name 'cross_validate'"`

Am I missing anything? (My sklearn lib is working well)

Comment: it would definety help if you (1) showed the error message and (2) tell the sklearn version you are using. my 2-cent is that you have to use the command from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score instead, but it is difficult to be sure due to lack of background information on your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your indication. I just noticed that it's working when I update the sklearn to 0.19.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that it's working when I update the sklearn to 0.19.